# Can anyone please help me to plot the following list of complex values?

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I tried to plot the complex values in *Mathematica* using the following code

```
ComplexListPlot[
 {-1.565553236342579`+0.5086219029293979` I,
  -1.330625340792095`+0.9667548836877041` I,
  -0.9430644117513098`+1.298005155976131` I,
  -0.46974165011582125`+1.4457161432870014` I
  }
]
```

but I got the output as

```
ComplexListPlot[{-1.565553236342579`+0.5086219029293979` I,-1.330625340792095`+0.9667548836877041` I,-0.9430644117513098`+1.298005155976131` I,-0.46974165011582125`+1.4457161432870014` I}]
```

Which is same as the input which I gave. Can anybody please help me.

Comment: See this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=complex+list+plot

Comment: Your code works for me.  Try clearing the kernel.

Comment: If I copy and paste your expression into a *Mathematica* notebook it produces a plot for me.  I see that `ComplexListPlot` was added in V12, and your report hints that you may be working with a earlier version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a version earlier than 12, you can simply split out the real and imaginary components of the data. For example:

```
myList = Table[Power[x, 3] /. x -> Exp[I t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]
ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ myList]
```

Comment: `ListPlot[ReIm /@ myList]`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

```
data = N@Array[Exp[(2 π I)/32 #] &, 32];
```

### Mathematica v12

```
ComplexListPlot[
 data
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 ]
```

### Mathematica v10

```
ListPlot[
 ReIm @ data
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 ]
```

### Earlier

```
ListPlot[
 Through /@ {Re, Im} /@ data
 , AspectRatio -> 1
 , Frame-> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]